# Significato di "indovinello" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Con gli occhi chiusi* di Federigo Tozzi  ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Pietro, con gratitudine, sentiva vicino a Ghìsola le sue prime emozioni delicate. Ammirò un fiore quando gli venne voglia di coglierlo per lei; e, non arrischiandosi, lo buttava via; quando era ancora per non crederci, provando una diminuzione di se stesso. E come tutta la natura gli apparve a un tratto misteriosa, con violenza! Qualche cosa da disperarsene! 
>      Era stato bocconi in terra, chiudendo tra le braccia un pulcino per tenerlo con sé! Aveva aiutato le formiche, togliendo dal loro cammino un bastone che dovevano valicare esitando e poi disperate: tremolando con un chicco troppo grosso, che le faceva cadere capovolte! Teneva con tenerezza un **indovinello** in mano, e lo rimproverava quando volava via!

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "indovinello" in questo brano? Ho cercato su parecchi dizionari, inclusi il [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/indovinello) e il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000853.jpg), ma nessuna delle accezioni che ho trovato sembra avere senso nel contesto del testo.

Forse dovreste sapere che si tratta di in romanzo con molti toscanismi. Aggiungo anche che molti dei vocaboli su cui ho avuto dei dubbi li ho trovati soltanto sul GDLI, che cita nelle voci corrispondenti molti esempi di Tozzi, tra i quali molti di questo romanzo.

Comment: Ho trovato questo articolo della Crusca in cui almeno la parola non è usata nel senso di enigma, ma di riflesso di luce: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/origine-di-gibigiana/218. Non so però come potrebbe aver senso nel brano (se non in senso poetico e figurato), che sembra riferito a un uccello.

Comment: Data la descrizione posso intuire che si tratti d'un insetto, forse una coccinella? È solo un'intuizione però

Comment: Credo che @GrandTorini sia andato vicino alla soluzione: penso si tratti di una mantide religiosa (Mantis religiosa); in greco *mantis* significa profeta, indovino.

Comment: Ah, interessante, @RiccardoDeContardi!

Answer (score 4):

Credo che la frase vada letta in relazione ad una precedente, ovvero:

> E come tutta la natura gli apparve a un tratto **misteriosa**, con
> violenza

Da cui l'uso di "indovinello" per indicare le piccole creature con cui il protagonista interagisce (ad esempio un pulcino, una formica e quant'altro), da interpretare proprio nell'accezione di enigma, mistero.
Per il protagonista ogni elemento naturale è un indovinello, in quanto parte di quella natura che gli appare misteriosa.

Comment: Sembra una buona intuizione!